# php_dblib enabled but not in phpinfo (Windows)

Tags: php, windows, driver, wampserver, freetds

I need to connect to a remote Sybase database with PHP 5.4.5 and I therefore enable the driver `php_dblib` (FreeTDS) for PHP and it shows as is in Wampserver but when I look at the `phpinfo()` results, there is nothing about `dblib`.

My application (Zend) returns

> **Fatal error:** Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver' in ... PropelPDO->__construct('dblib:host=ans...', 'sa', '', Array)

I am running Wampserver 2.2, Apache 2.2.3 and PHP 5.4.5.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you restart the wamp server, if yes did it throw any error pop message?

Comment: I did yes of course and I didn't have any popup. I had one earlier today, probably about this but I can't tell what it was and it doesn't show anymore (nothing in the logs either) and the `php.ini` still seem okay just like the list of loaded extensions for PHP